# Complex integral with pole

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I am doing GRE problems to prepare for the subject exam. My complex analysis is a bit rusty, can someone give me a hint here:

$$I=\oint_C \frac{\cos z}{z(z-\pi)} dz$$

where $C$ is the circle $\vert z -1 \vert = 2$.

Am I correct in my following intuition.

First we are considering the circle with radius $\sqrt{2}$ centered at $(1,0)$ on the complex plane correct? And we have two points to consider as poles $z=0,\pi$ but one of them is outside the circle correct? Namely, $z=\pi$ is outside and only the origin is inside it. So Do I calculate the residue at the one pole I have? Also if they were both outside, it would be zero correct?

Comment: please fix the discrepancy between $x$ and $z$. Why do you say the radius is  $\sqrt{2}$? it is just $2$.

Comment: sorry got it confused with the real case where its written as $x^2+y^2=r^2$

Comment: You've got the right idea, barring the details that @peek-a-boo has mentioned.

Comment: So, yes, you just have to calculate the residue at $z=0$ (which should be easy since the stuff other than $\frac{1}{z}$ is holomorphic there)

Comment: awesome I got it!! its just $2 \pi i \frac{-1}{\pi}=-2i$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So $I$ has two singularities to consider, at $z=0,\pi$.  By the residue theorem we know that

$$\oint_C f(z) = 2 \pi i \sum_{k=1}^m \eta(C;a_k) \text{Res} (f;a_k)$$

Where $\eta$ is winding number. Since the winding number for $z=\pi$ is zero, we need to only compute the residue at $z=0$ which has winding number $1$. Then we get

$$\oint_C f(z) = 2 \pi i (\frac{-1}{\pi})=-2i$$

as needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply Cauchy's integral formula to $f(z)=\frac{\cos z}{z-\pi}$, getting\begin{align}\oint_{|z-1|=2}\frac{\cos z}{z(z-\pi)}\,\mathrm dz&=\oint_{|z-1|=2}\frac{f(z)}z\,\mathrm dz\\&=2\pi if(0)\\&=-\frac{2\pi i}\pi\\&=-2i.\end{align}